# MySQL Error Help: Unknown Column in On Clause

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm trying to put together a query that pulls data from multiple tables, but I'm getting an odd error:

`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'esjp_layout.section_id' in 'on clause'`

The table and column referenced certainly exist, and it's spelled correctly.  This is the query I'm working with.  Any ideas what is wrong?

```
SELECT
    esjp_section_refs.section_label,
    esjp_content.primary_key, esjp_content.content, esjp_content.summary_id, 
    esjp_role_refs.role_label, 
    esjp_users.first_name, esjp_users.last_name,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(esjp_content.sys_time)
FROM esjp_content
    INNER JOIN esjp_section_refs ON esjp_layout.section_id = esjp_section_refs.primary_key
    INNER JOIN esjp_layout ON esjp_content.primary_key = esjp_layout.content_id 
    INNER JOIN esjp_role_refs ON esjp_content.role_ref = esjp_role_refs.primary_key
    INNER JOIN esjp_users ON esjp_content.author_id = esjp_users.primary_key
WHERE esjp_layout.primary_key = 1
ORDER BY esjp_layout.section_id ASC, esjp_layout.position ASC ;
```

*P.S. I know this query is somewhat wordy, but it's being assembled programatically, so character count doesn't concern me.*

Comment: A column named "section_id" probably exists in table "esjp_layout". But certainly not in the tables "esjp_content" or "esjp_section_refs" which you try to join _with that specific ON clause_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the table that is being joined in your `ON` clause isn't in the query yet.

Instead:

```
SELECT
    esjp_section_refs.section_label,
    esjp_content.primary_key, esjp_content.content, esjp_content.summary_id, 
    esjp_role_refs.role_label, 
    esjp_users.first_name, esjp_users.last_name,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(esjp_content.sys_time)
FROM esjp_content
    INNER JOIN esjp_layout ON esjp_content.primary_key = esjp_layout.content_id 
    INNER JOIN esjp_section_refs ON esjp_layout.section_id = esjp_section_refs.primary_key    
    INNER JOIN esjp_role_refs ON esjp_content.role_ref = esjp_role_refs.primary_key
    INNER JOIN esjp_users ON esjp_content.author_id = esjp_users.primary_key
WHERE esjp_layout.primary_key = 1
ORDER BY esjp_layout.section_id ASC, esjp_layout.position ASC ;
```

In other words you have to join in a table by joining it to a table that is already in your query. They have to be joined in order, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining esjp_layout after the on close, try switching this if possible so that when the on clause hists, the table is already joined on

```
   FROM_UNIXTIME(esjp_content.sys_time)
   FROM esjp_content
   INNER JOIN esjp_section_refs ON **esjp_layout.section_id** = esjp_section_refs.primary_key
   INNER JOIN **esjp_layout** ON esjp_content.primary_key = esjp_layout.content_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table only after you joined it. So switch the join order to

```
SELECT
    esjp_section_refs.section_label,
    esjp_content.primary_key, esjp_content.content, esjp_content.summary_id, 
    esjp_role_refs.role_label, 
    esjp_users.first_name, esjp_users.last_name,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(esjp_content.sys_time)
FROM esjp_content
    INNER JOIN esjp_layout ON esjp_content.primary_key = esjp_layout.content_id 
    INNER JOIN esjp_section_refs ON esjp_layout.section_id = esjp_section_refs.primary_key        
    INNER JOIN esjp_role_refs ON esjp_content.role_ref = esjp_role_refs.primary_key
    INNER JOIN esjp_users ON esjp_content.author_id = esjp_users.primary_key
WHERE esjp_layout.primary_key = 1
ORDER BY esjp_layout.section_id ASC, esjp_layout.position ASC ;
```